# How to refresh Cursor?

Tags: android, service, cursor

My app is a service who check if are new message in inbox every 2 seconds( for debug), but when I receive a new message the app still show me old value and not update to the new( e.g. If I had 2 messages in inbox and now I get a new, the app will still tell me I have 2 messages). Here is the code:

```
public class SMSS extends IntentService
{
    Cursor inboxCursor = null;
    Timer myTimer;

    // ...

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        inboxCursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
        Log.d("Cursor0", Integer.toString(inboxCursor.getPosition()));

        // ...

        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(jParser, getContentResolver()), START_TIME, RETRY_TIME);
    }
}

public class Task extends TimerTask
{
    Cursor inboxCursor = null;

    public Task(ContentResolver contentResolver)
        inboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Log.d("Cursor0", Integer.toString(inboxCursor.getCount()));
    }
```

I check with debugger to see if the counts of messages is changed, but remain the same...
How to refresh/update the cursor to get the real values?

Comment: did you know that twenry something lines of your code can be replaced with one line: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver(android.net.Uri, boolean, android.database.ContentObserver) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think to refresh the cursor you need to query again.
So better be call

```
public void run()
{
inboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
Log.d("Cursor0", Integer.toString(inboxCursor.getCount()));
}
```

Comment: That's correct.  You can't "refresh" a cursor.  You need a new one.  Consider a CursorLoader.